# In JMeter I need to extract a specific Regular Expression

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

In the following String:

```
Events('1234', '123456', '', 'QW233Cdse');
```

I need to extract `"QW233Cdse"`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does the line has each time 3 parameters ? And u always want the last one ? Do the two first parameters always contain only digits ? Does the thirdf parameter is always close by a single quote ? Does the parameter contains only alphanumeric characters ? If it's yes for all the answer I would do `\w+(?='\))`

Comment: I need the last one!   But the two first parameters are dynamically generate! they could be change!

Comment: From JMETER-  RegEX Extractor, does not work!

Comment: If you show the code you are trying to use, it helps us help you

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are working with regular expressions then its very important that we should look for the static text in the test string that can help to create a strong regular expression.

As in your case, "Events()" seems to be a static text containing dynamic value in the round parenthesis so in order to generate the regular expression you need to keep 'Events()' text and add the expression in the round parenthesis as mentioned below:

Test String: Events('1234', '123456', '', 'QW233Cdse');

Regular Expression can be:

- Events(.'(.)');
- Events(.* '(.+?)');

Note: The backslash before round parentheses would avoid interpreting the round braces as unescaped character. For example, a parenthesis "(" begins the definition of a quantifier, but the leading backslash of parenthesis "(" indicates that the regular expression should match the parenthesis.

Regular expression is most important item to learn when you are working with load testing tools and you can refer to below blog post to get more information on regular expression:

- https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/

Let me know if you have any further question

Answer (score 0):

The relevant regular expression would be something like:

```
Events\(.* '(.+?)'\);
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Demo]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score -1):

Try using this regex:

```
\w+(?='\))
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex would be:

> , '([^']+?)');

Configuration would be:

[image: REE Configuration]